# bitmap.save is not saving exact pixel color in c#

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap

I've changed all pixels color in one bitmap file with "bitmap.SetPixel" .when I  save the bitmap on PC , the saved file has different colors for each pixel when I open it in photoshop .. !! the saved colors are close but not the same.. please help me.

set pixel color:

```
Bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, MyColor);
```

save bitmap :

```
Bitmap.Save(MyPath, PicImage.RawFormat );
```

Comment: Well, what __is__ the [RawFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat(v=vs.110).aspx) ? If it is jpg, all pixels will be re-encoded and a very slight change in the colors is to be expected.. Png would help..

Comment: Thank you.. you are right I should use png format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [Image.RawFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat(v=vs.110).aspx) is basically a shorthand for *'use the original image format!'*

So, if your image source is a **lossy compressed** format like `jpeg` you are saving , i.e. **re-encoding** it in the same compressed format, but, most likely using a different compressor codec and/or different quality etc parameters.

So you can expect some slight color shifts.

Even with the very same codec etc a `jpeg` would have to create a different version of the compression tables just for the one pixel you are changing..

Make sure the original image uses a lossless compression, like `png` or some `tif` formats to avoid this effect.

To be sure you may want to specify the format explicitly.